# NaN error during backpropagation of torch.sqrt() even though an epsilon is added inside the square root

Tags: pytorch, nan, backpropagation

I am training a neural network with custom loss function that calls `torch.sqrt()` at one point. To avoid getting NaN gradients during backpropagation I add a small epsilon value inside the squareroot, however the model parameters still diverge into NaN values from time to time.

I set `torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)`, which backtracked the NaN error to the following sqrt function.

```
b = torch.sqrt((m[...,0,0] - m[...,1,1])**2/4 + m[...,0,1]**2  + torch.finfo(torch.float).tiny)
```

Since the derivative sqrt(\epsilon)'=1/sqrt(epsilon) (approximately 4e18) is still very big, I increased the size of the epsilon value to `torch.finfo(torch.half).tiny` (which equals roughly 6e-5). The error still persists though. At this point I am out of ideas and also couldn't find any solutions on the internet, so I appreciate any help.

p.s. the optimizer used is L-BFGS if that matters

Comment: Are you using mixed precision? Can you reproduce the error when using `torch.float32`?

Comment: Not that I know of. I can try setting all tensors and models to `torch.float32` manually, but that's already the default type anyways, isn't it?

Comment: Just realized I never reported back. The error was indeed that I didn't enforce the same precision for all tensors and models. Thanks for the help :)